# GWT application is not showing in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, gwt

I have a GWT 2.6 app which works fine on every browser except in IE (IE11). I am compiling application for all browsers. Using developer tools (console posts) i can see that application does load as it should be, but the page is blank and nothing is shown. No error appears in console and there is only a warning...

> HTML1524: Invalid HTML5 DOCTYPE. Consider using the interoperable form "`<!DOCTYPE html>`".
>   File: user, Line: 1, Column: 1

...concerning application HTML file. I removed all Views and Widgets and left only basic view with some background and picture, and it still does not load properly only in IE.
I tried adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5,6,8,9" >
```

to app html file but it doesn't make a difference nor does a Compatibility View settings and changing Document Type. I really do not care so much about app working in older IE versions, but >9 is preferable.

What am i missing here?

**EDIT:**

Actually the problem was having DockLayoutPanel in my View. Changed DockLayoutPanel into DockPanel and the application appeared (with some differences comparing to UI in other browsers).

Comment: How the current DTD looks like? That warning gives you a tip what you should use as DTD.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your html host page is properly formatted. It should start with the DOCTYPE declaration, followed immediately by `<html>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        ...
```

Comment: I know, this is html host page:
`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5,6,8,9" > 


<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="myApp.css"> ...`

Although, when i change starting declaration with <!DOCTYPE html> the problem which appeared in IE, appears in every browser. Also without error in console.

Comment: Remove `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"` line. And do you even try to set the mode to transitional? Many GWT widgets don't even work in that mode.